# How to customize a delegate of NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

According to the Apple document when you process the return data you can provide a completion handler block or provide your own custom delegate objects.Here comes the question: I can just use the Block with the method `downloadTaskWithRequest: completionHandler:`and process the data in the block, or Use the method `downloadTaskWithRequest:` and process the data in the delegate that provided by NSURLSession such as   `-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location` .

So I can not figure out how to use my own custom delegate and how it look like? I`m finding some example

Comment: Using the completion handler rendition is generally easier. I would generally only advise using the delegate-based rendition if you need some custom behavior or if you're doing this for background sessions. There are plenty of examples of delegate based `NSURLSession` (and I'd start with Apple's own [URL Loading Guide: Using NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1)). Or google "NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate example".

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstand the concept as there are three ways to process the data. First is the block ,second is the system-provided delegate and the third is the custom delegate. I just figure out that use the block equals ues the system-provided delegate and use delegate method equals customize a delegate.

Comment: I might describe that a little differently: You can use completion blocks or you can use session delegate. If you use delegate-based approach, you must instantiate your own `NSURLSession` object (that's the only way to specify what the delegate is). If you don't need your own delegate (i.e., you're only going to use completion blocks), you can use a system-provided shared `NSURLSession`, which is provided for your convenience, (but you can also use your own session object, too).